# downloading file from FTP server: the given path's format is not supported

Tags: c#

I have written this code to download file from FTP server but it shows error message that The given path's format is not supported.

```
 WebClient web = new WebClient();
 byte[] filedata = web.DownloadData("ftp://localhost/images/" 
                                    + "/" + "aaaasa.txt");
 FileStream file = File.Create("ftp://localhost/images/"+"/"+"aaaasa.txt");
 file.Write(filedata, 0, filedata.Length);
 file.Close();
```

Answer (score 4):

Double slashes in your urls look suspicious.

e.g.:

```
"ftp://localhost/images/"+"/"+"aaaasa.txt"
```

gives

```
ftp://localhost/images//aaaasa.txt
```

is that what you meant?

Also `File.Create` is only meant for local files.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the others said about the double slash ("//") in your FTP path, please note that the local file can not contain a protocol:

```
File.Create("ftp://localhost/images/"+"/"+"aaaasa.txt")
```

That doesn't work. Please provide a local file name like in the following example:

```
FileStream file = File.Create(@"C:\Temp\aaaasa.txt");
file.Write(filedata, 0, filedata.Length);
file.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, that the problem you have is caused by the fact that the path you given is incorrect due to an "/" too much
what you have written now:

```
web.DownloadData("ftp://localhost/images/" + "/" + "aaaasa.txt")
```

it results in "ftp://localhost/images//aaaasa.txt"

if you would remove the + "/" I think you might be fine.
This goes as well for the file.create method.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the double slashes. Also, the File class works against local filesystems, which it appears is what you are trying to write the data to. Why do you have the ftp:// in that path?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) for this purpose. Follow by link. there are number of useful examples in "Examples" section.